# Input value to selected Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get the value to the input that was clicked? At the moment the value shows in all inputs. How can I show the value in the selected input?

Here is my code:

```js
$('.ui-spinner').click(function () {
    $('.cn-wrapper').show();
});

$(".cn-wrapper li span").click(function () {
    var textValue = $(this).text();
    $('.ui-spinner').val(textValue);
});
```

```css
.cn-wrapper {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span >50</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>100</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>200</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span >300</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span >400</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span >500</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>600</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>700</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Set</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input id="user1" class="ui-spinner"></input>
<input id="user2" class="ui-spinner"></input>
<input id="user3" class="ui-spinner"></input>
```

Here is an external [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmLjr5cf/).

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/fmLjr5cf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a variable outside of your click listeners that references the `lastClickedInput` like so:

```
var lastClickedInput = null;

$('.ui-spinner').click(function () {
    $('.cn-wrapper').show();
    lastClickedInput = $( this );
});

$(".cn-wrapper li span").click(function () {
     var textValue = $(this).text();

     if ( lastClickedInput )
         lastClickedInput.val( textValue );
});
```

Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/richardgirges/fmLjr5cf/6/

Answer (score 5):

You would need to store the last clicked `input` in a variable which is in scope of both functions, something like this:

```
var $target;

$('.ui-spinner').click(function () {
    $('.cn-wrapper').show();
    $('.target').removeClass('target');
    $target = $(this);
});

$(".cn-wrapper li span").click(function () {
    var textValue = $(this).text();
    $target.val(textValue);
    $('.cn-wrapper').hide();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmLjr5cf/3/)

Alternatively, you could add a class to the selected input on click and then target that when setting the value:

```
$('.ui-spinner').click(function () {
    $('.cn-wrapper').show();
    $(this).addClass('target');
});

$(".cn-wrapper li span").click(function () {
    var textValue = $(this).text();
    $('.target').val(textValue);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fmLjr5cf/7/)